# Perform action depending on amount of times a key is pressed?

Tags: javascript

The keypress function below calls a certain function depending on how many times a given key is pressed. On execution, only the first if statement runs, and the second one does not.

```
$(document).keypress(function(number) {
      var pressCount = 0;
      pressCount++;

      if (number.which == 67 || number.which == 99) {
        if (pressCount = 1) {
          callThisFunction();
        } else if (pressCount = 2) {
          callThisOtherFunction();
          }
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Its perhaps happening because "pressCount" is reset to 0 every time the function runs.

try the following tweak:

```
    var pressCount = 0;

$(document).keypress(function(number) {
      pressCount++;

      if (number.which == 67 || number.which == 99) {
        if (pressCount == 1) {
          callThisFunction();
        } else if (pressCount == 2) {
          callThisOtherFunction();
          }
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `=` sign inside your `if` statement. Change to:

```
if (pressCount == 1) {
    callThisFunction();
} else if (pressCount == 2) {
    callThisOtherFunction();
}
```

Also declare you `pressCount` variable outside of your function. Otherwise it will be reset to 0 everytime you press a key.

```
var pressCount = 0;

$(document).keypress(function(number) {
   ... // rest of your code
```